# Can I execute npm install upon the installation of a NuGet package?

Tags: npm, nuget, nuget-package

I'm creating a NuGet package which contains TypeScript dependencies...node_modules stuff. I don't want to include the node_modules as part of the package, so I'd prefer to execute `npm install` after the package installation completes. I've installed the package on a test website, and if I *manually* execute `npm install` it works.

I can put it in the readme to execute `npm install` after the package is completed, but I'd prefer to execute it automatically when the install is complete. Is there any way to make that happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Historically, we could write an *Install.ps1* PowerShell script to invoke certain actions when installing a NuGet package. However, as of NuGet version 3, this feature is [no longer supported](https://blog.nuget.org/20151008/NuGet-3-What-and-Why.html):

> Powershell script support was modified to no longer execute install and uninstall scripts, but init scripts are still executed.

The *Init.ps1* script described above allows us to execute actions when a someone installs our package. Although the blog post above suggests that we can still use *Init.ps1* scripts in our packages, the lack of recent documentation for this feature and a [comment](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4318) from a NuGet developer seem to indicate that *Init.ps1* is also deprecated and that the behavior may not be available in the future. This makes sense if we consider that NuGet also aims to support Mac and Linux for Mono/.NET Core projects, and these systems do not yet include ubiquitous support for PowerShell like Windows (but [they may eventually](https://github.com/powershell/powershell)).

For these reasons, I cannot recommend at this time that we automate the package's post-install steps using NuGet's built-in features. The script that runs `npm install` must also handle challenges on systems where the *npm* program is missing or not available in the `PATH`, and some users may not like the idea of the package installing [and running](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/141702881055/package-install-scripts-vulnerability) arbritrary code. I think it's fair for the project in question to simply instruct the end user in the README to run `npm install` after installation. Projects with more complex post-installation steps can instruct end users to run a script that executes each step. If you still wish to try using *Init.ps1*, continue reading:

The [current NuGet docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package) omit information about *Init.ps1*, but [older documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20110426155337/http://nuget.codeplex.com/documentation?title=Creating%20a%20Package) from 2007 contains this description:

> Init.ps1 runs the first time a package is installed in a solution. If the same package is installed into additional projects in the solution, the script is not run during those installations. The script also runs every time the solution is opened. For example, if you install a package, close Visual Studio, and then start Visual Studio and open the solution, the Init.ps1script runs again.
>   ...
>   These files should be located in the tools directory of your package.

So, we can create an *Init.ps1* file in the *tools/* directory for our package which might look like the following:

```powershell
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

Set-Location Path\To\Project\With\Node\Dependencies
npm install
```

...and then generate the NuGet package. The `param()` statement for the NuGet convention-based scripts provides the following values:

> - `$installPath` is the path to your package install
> - `$toolsPath` is the path to the tools directory under the package
> - `$package` is your package
> - `$project` is the project you are installing the application to. Note: This will be null in Init.ps1. It doesn't have a reference to a particular project because it runs at the solution level.

Because this script runs whenever we load a solution, it could slow down Visual Studio. We can add a condition to the script that checks if the packages are installed before running *npm*. Note that this functionality is restricted to NuGet operations run from Visual Studio or the Package Manager Console and likely will not work using the standalone NuGet CLI program because of the coupling of these scripts to projects and solutions.

- [Discussion to reintroduce *Install.ps1* to NuGet](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1020)

Comment: Yeah, this is where I'm at - no safe way to do it that isn't likely to be deprecated. Updating the README seems to be the only option so far, which really isn't any good because people don't read them.

Comment: @Chris - wish I could help more. This may not apply to your package in particular, but it may be worth mentioning: it's possible to distribute the package *through npm* as well, perhaps as a secondary installation option for end users, which would effectively eliminate the need to run `npm install`. This can be a lot more feasible for private teams too.